# Create express server without port

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, http, tcp

I would like to know if is possible create a server using express without serving any port. I need create a server just for socket connection with other application using TCP protocol.

Maybe express is not the best tool for that? Cause express is for web frameworks, and i don't really need ANY port at all.

Currently i'm doing:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(8000, function() {
  console.log('Connected in port 8000');
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, just drop the `listen`, and probably even `createServer` as it's deprecated ?

Comment: is createServer deprecated? what should i use instead?

Comment: Oh, wait, you're probably using `require('http').createServer` which isn't deprecated, but `express.createServer` is

Comment: yeap, i'm using the http :).

Comment: http://www.hacksparrow.com/tcp-socket-programming-in-node-js.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not going to have an http server listening for incoming HTTP connections, then you don't even need an Express server at all since it is a web server framework.  No need to use the Express framework at all.

Instead, you can just use the built-in `net` module and use plain TCP socket functions in that module (see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_server) for creating a plain TCP server).  If you are going to be listening for incoming TCP connections, you will still need to be listening on a specific port - that's how TCP works.  An incoming connection connects on a specific port and it must connect to a server listening on that specific port.

Comment: I am a little confuse hehehe.. I create the TCP connection in my localhost in the 9000 port, so i need create the http connection in the same port, too?

Comment: @FátimaAlves - Please clarify your question.  The client and server MUST be operating on the same port.  That's how TCP works.  So, if you're working on port 9000, then the server must be listening on port 9000 and the client must connect to the server on port 9000.  There is no such thing as a TCP connection that is not associated with a port.

Comment: I'm not using a client at all for the socket. I'm using two servers in a pub/sub pattern, one server is listening for tcp://localhost:9000 and other is sending messages in the same port. My question is about the http port. Do I need to listen to any port on the server that will only get the messages through the socket, or it is not necessary?

Comment: The "client" in this case is whatever computer initiates the TCP connection.  It must connect to some other computer on a port.  Always.  That's how TCP works.  Yes, the server that wants to receive the connection MUST listen on a port.  The other server that wants to create the connection MUST connect on that same port.  All connections are made on a port.  So, what's the real question here or the reluctance?  Just specify port 9000 for both the listening server and the server making the connection to the other server.

Comment: I think I 'm not being clear enough. I understood in relation to the ports on the TCP protocol, what I want to know is if it is necessary to listen to any port on the HTTP protocol on the server that will have no HTTP request , and if the answer is yes, how do I create a server without hearing a HTTP port using the express.

Comment: @FátimaAlves - Please read my answer again.  Express is for managing HTTP requests on an HTTP server.  If you're not going to use HTTP as your protocol, then don't use Express at all - don't even `require()` it.  Use a plain TCP socket connection and server and invent or use some other protocol.  If you are going to use HTTP as the protocol, then you need an HTTP server listening on a port.  There is no such thing as a plain TCP server or HTTP server that is not listening on a port.  It does not exist.